# not meaningful for factors in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes :

Rules:

```
Column Rule Argument
A      a    1
B      b    2
```

mydata:

```
A    B    C    D
re   ..   ..   ..
t    ..   ..   ..
edw  ..   ..   ..
```

now i get the column from Rules using

```
col <- Rules[1,1] which returns the column name A
```

I want to subset mydata based on the length of col:

```
subset(mydata , nchar(mydata[[col]])) > 2)
```

It should return me this record from mydata

```
edw  ..   ..   ..
```

However, it returns :

> Warning message:
>   In Ops.factor(nchar(mydata[[col]])) > 2) :
>     ‘>’ not meaningful for factors

I tried converting `mydata[[col]]` to `as.numeric` before using `nchar` but no use.

Comment: What is the output of `str(mydf)`? Also try adding your data using `dput(mydata)`

Comment: I had changed the actual data but it returned something like:                                       'data.frame': 50001 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ A   : chr  "re" "t" "edw" ...

Comment: You need to convert whatever column is holding factors to `character` class using `as.character(column)`

Comment: Sure , I'll give it a try, however is it due to the subset containing some columns as factors or the column  used in nchar being of type factor ( which is not the case btw as its chr)?